# Login Logo Not displaying in oracle apex 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to create my own logo in login page.First i uploaded image at =>Shared Components/Static Workspace Files (also tried Static Application Files).Then used below code +>Login Page+>Css Inline.But i am not getting any logo.any idea where i am doing any wrong or any clue to do cross check.

```
span.t-Login-logo {
background-image: url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Fjimages1.png);
background-size: cover;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: can you check with the html inspector what is the route? But I solved this issue running java -jar ords.war validate

Comment: http://10.185.244.180:8080/ords/wkspc_aps/r/files/static/v2/Fjimages1.png

Comment: Did you try  java -jar ords.war validate?